# Programming error with WTForms StringField writing to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

My database is a Postgres instance.
My model is defined as:

```
from app import db
class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'device'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
```

my from is defined as:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField

class EditDevices(FlaskForm):
    device_name = StringField("Device Name", validators=[])
    submit = SubmitField['Submit']
```

I get an error in the form that says:

```
    sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'StringField' [SQL: 'UPDATE device SET name=%(name)s WHERE device.id = %(device_id)s'] [parameters: {'name':  <wtforms.fields.core.StringField object at 0x110580c18>, 'device_id': 208}]
```

any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is incomplete-- you're not showing where you actually try to set the model data and save it to the database, but the error says `<wtforms.fields.core.StringField object at 0x110580c18>` is the value you're setting to the `name` attribute, so you're likely doing:

```
device = Device()
device.name = form.device_name
db.session.add(device)
db.session.commit()
```

Which would lead to something similar to the error you're seeing because `form.device_name` is a `StringField` whereas you want the user-submitted data.  To get the data from the form element you need to use the `.data` property:

```
device = Device()
device.name = form.device_name.data
db.session.add(device)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

use email.data place of data

```
class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=6,max=15)])
    password_confirm = PasswordField("Confirm Password", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=6,max=15), EqualTo('password')])
    first_name = StringField("First Name", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=55)])
    last_name = StringField("Last Name", validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=55)])
    submit = SubmitField("Register Now")

    def validate_email(self,email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=**email.data**).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError("Email is already in use. Pick another one.")
```